# NLog Writing a GUID to database

Tags: c#, sql, guid, nlog

I am having trouble inserting a guid Id each time a log is written in the database. It throws these errors:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in System.Data.SqlClient.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in NLog.dll
```

What I have so far:

```
    @"INSERT INTO [dbo].[Nlogs] 
            (Id,Message) 
            values
            (@Id,@Message)";

    databaseTarget.Parameters.Add(new DatabaseParameterInfo("@Id", Guid.NewGuid().ToString()));
    databaseTarget.Parameters.Add(new DatabaseParameterInfo("@Message", "${message}"));
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please add the stack trace!

Comment: @Fruchtzwerg That is all there is. It just repeats those two lines whenever a log is to be created. I think it is due to 'Id' being the primary key and it errors out because it cannot use the same guid twice. How would I get it to create a new Guid for each entry? I removed Id as a primary key and it logs fine with each run all having the same guid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ended up doing this:

```
@"INSERT INTO [dbo].[Nlogs] 
        (Id,Message) 
        values
        (NewID(),@Message)";

databaseTarget.Parameters.Add(new DatabaseParameterInfo("@Message", "${message}"));
```

Answer (score 1):

> How would I get it to create a new Guid for each entry?

Use [`${guid}`](https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Guid-Layout-Renderer) or [event properties](https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/EventProperties-Layout-Renderer)

for example:

```xml
<target name="db"
        xsi:type="Database"
        connectionStringName="NLogConn"
        commandText="NSERT INTO [dbo].[Nlogs] 
            (Id,Message) 
            values
            (@Id,@Message)" >
  <parameter name="@Id"      layout="${guid}" dbType="Guid" />
  <parameter name="@Message" layout="${message}" />
</target>
```

Update: added `dbType` attribute to the example above, that would fix any conversion issues! You need NLog 4.6+ for that.

From the [docs](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Database-target):

> dbType - One of the values of DbType (e.g. "Int32", "Decimal", "DateTime"), or a value of DBType like prefixed with the property name, e.g. "SqlDbType.NChar" will set the property "SqlDbType" on "NChar". Another example: "NpgsqlDbType.Json" with NpgsqlParameter. Introduced in NLog 4.6

Comment: I tried ${guid} but I still get the same exceptions

Comment: Could it be because I am using .net core?

Comment: I'm not an expert of NLog, but when I used ${guid}, I had the same error. so I changed the type in the DB from uniqueidentifier to varchar and I saw that it generated a string without the dashes. I changed to ${guid:format=D} and it worked.

Comment: Update: added `dbType` attribute to the example above, that would fix any conversion issues! You need NLog 4.6+ for that. Then `format=D` is also not needed